# Confint() with glm {stats} very, very slow

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval, binomial-coefficients

I have a problem with calculating OR confidence intervals from a glm in the latest version of R, but I have not had this issue before.  With any glm where `family="binomial"`, no matter how simple the model is, it will easily allow me to extract the summary and exp(coef(model)), however when I try to extract the `confint()` or `exp(confint(model))`, the "Waiting for profiling to be done..." message is displayed and nothing happens (I've waited up to 10 mins then cancelled the procedure, this usually takes only seconds on my machine).  Any ideas what might be tripping this function up?  I've tried it on `multiple datasets` and variables, with the same result.  Any ideas why it is taking so long/failing to finish?

Answer (score 11):

Well, for some unknown reason, specifying `exp(confint.default(model))` leads to instant resolution of this problem.

Comment: It should be noted that `confint.default()` and `confint()` do give slightly different results.

Comment: @Phil. That is true. But I think the interpretations will end in the same conclusion for both methods.